# Access TransferSpreadsheet - Replace Data

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am exporting query from Access to an Excel sheet calles "tempIcIn". When the sheet is already existing in the file, TransferSpreadsheet will just create another sheet with the same name followed by a 1.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "tempIcIn", outputPath, True
```

I would like to overwrite the data which is already in the created sheet.

Answer (score 0):

http://btabdevelopment.com/export-a-table-or-query-to-excel-specific-worksheet-on-specific-workbook/

```vb
Public Function SendTQ2XLWbSheet(strTQName As String, strSheetName As String, strFilePath As String)
' strTQName is the name of the table or query you want to send to Excel
' strSheetName is the name of the sheet you want to send it to
' strFilePath is the name and path of the file you want to send this data into.

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim ApXL As Object
    Dim xlWBk As Object
    Dim xlWSh As Object
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim strPath As String
    Const xlCenter As Long = -4108
    Const xlBottom As Long = -4107
    On Error GoTo err_handler

    strPath = strFilePath

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strTQName)

    Set ApXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set xlWBk = ApXL.Workbooks.Open(strPath)

    ApXL.Visible = True

    Set xlWSh = xlWBk.Worksheets(strSheetName)

    xlWsh.Activate

    xlWSh.Range("A1").Select

    For Each fld In rst.Fields
        ApXL.ActiveCell = fld.Name
        ApXL.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next

    rst.MoveFirst

    xlWSh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    xlWSh.Range("1:1").Select
    ' This is included to show some of what you can do about formatting.  You can comment out or delete
    ' any of this that you don't want to use in your own export.
    With ApXL.Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 12
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
    End With

    ApXL.Selection.Font.Bold = True

    With ApXL.Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .MergeCells = False
    End With

    ' selects all of the cells
    ApXL.ActiveSheet.Cells.Select

    ' does the "autofit" for all columns
    ApXL.ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    ' selects the first cell to unselect all cells
    xlWSh.Range("A1").Select

    rst.Close

    Set rst = Nothing

Exit_SendTQ2XLWbSheet: 
    Exit Function

err_handler:
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_SendTQ2XLWbSheet    
End Function
```

The link is just the code that should do the trick.

Comment: If this code helped please make it the answer, otherwise tell me what didn't work and I'll try to help.