# Run time error 424 when overwriting spreadsheet from Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error

I am attempting to overwrite an excel worksheet with the output from an Access query, using Access VBA. I nabbed and amended some great Access VBA code from [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828335/access-transferspreadsheet-replace-data/29832771#29832771). The task completes but right at the end I get a Run-time error:

> Run-time Error '424': Object Required

The amended code is below. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Const strFilePath As String = "C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\Test Tracker\APS_Timeline_Status.xlsm"
Private Const strTQName As String = "q_APS_Timeline_Status_For_Export"
Private Const strSheetName As String = "TimeLine_Status"

Sub Update_timeline_tracker()

    SendTQ2XLWbSheet(strTQName, strSheetName, strFilePath).Run

End Sub


Public Function SendTQ2XLWbSheet(strTQName As String, strSheetName As String, strFilePath As String)

' strTQName is the name of the table or query you want to send to Excel
' strSheetName is the name of the sheet you want to send it to
' strFilePath is the name and path of the file you want to send this data into.

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim ApXL As Object
    Dim xlWBk As Object
    Dim xlWSh As Object
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim strPath As String
    On Error GoTo err_handler
 DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    strPath = strFilePath

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strTQName)

    Set ApXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set xlWBk = ApXL.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
    Debug.Print strPath

    ApXL.Visible = True

    Set xlWSh = xlWBk.Worksheets(strSheetName)

    ApXL.DisplayAlerts = False

    xlWSh.Activate

    xlWSh.Range("A1").Select

    For Each fld In rst.Fields
        ApXL.ActiveCell = fld.Name
        ApXL.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next

    rst.MoveFirst

    xlWSh.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    ' selects the first cell to unselect all cells
    xlWSh.Range("A1").Select

    rst.Close
    xlWBk.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\Test Tracker\APS_Timeline_Status.xlsm"
    xlWBk.Close
    ApXL.Quit

    Set rst = Nothing

Exit_SendTQ2XLWbSheet:
    Exit Function

err_handler:
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_SendTQ2XLWbSheet
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Function
```

Comment: what happens if you make the `private const` a `public const`? They are outside of a procedure so I would think it should be public

Comment: Hi Liam. I've changed all the private const to public ones. The same  run-time error is found.

Comment: I cant see undefined objects. If you remove your error handling, what line does your error appear?

Comment: Thanks Liam. When I debug the error, it brings me to here: `SendTQ2XLWbSheet(strTQName, strSheetName, strFilePath).Run` and when I move down through the code, the error appears specifically at `End Function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the issue here is that `SendTQ2XLWbSheet` is a function, and not an object. Therefore the `.run` part of your procedure cannot run something that isn't an object. This will be why your error is suggesting that an object is required.

To "run" a sub or a function in the way you require, you have to use the term "call" and hence the solution is:

```
Sub Update_timeline_tracker()

    call SendTQ2XLWbSheet(strTQName, strSheetName, strFilePath)

End Sub
```

Comment: Liam - you're a genius. Thanks a million!

Comment: No problem. I was just looking over the function itself and I think that you need a `docmd.setwarnings true` after the line `Set rst = Nothing`. The reason is that you should return the `setwarnings` back to true but in your code this is only happening when an error occurs. Which leads me to think setting it to false in the first place is unnecessary.